# AngularJS directive not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that seems to set everything properly when Angular instantiates the page, but doesn't update when I interact with its components.

HTML :

```
<div class="app-table col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" app-table>
    <header>
        <span class="col-xs-12">Subscriptions</span>
    </header>
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="user-controls">
            <span class="page-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="page"/>
            <span>/ {{summary.subscriptions.pages}}</span>
            <span class="page-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="results-text">Results 1 - {{summary.subscriptions.labels.length}} of {{summary.subscriptions.total}}</span>
    </div>
    <table class="col-xs-12 table-striped">
        <thead>
            <td class="col-xs-9">Name</td>
            <td class="col-xs-3">Subscribers</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="label in summary.subscriptions.labels | limitTo: 5 : offset">
                <td class="col-xs-9">{{label.name}}</td>
                <td class="col-xs-3">{{label.subscribers}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', 'DashboardService', function($scope, DashboardService) {
    $scope.summary = {};

    $scope.init = function() {
        DashboardService.getSummary().then(function(response){
            $scope.summary = response;
        });
    };

    $scope.init();
}]);
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('appTable', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        scope.offset = 0;
        scope.page = 1;

        elem.find('.page-up').bind('click', function(){
            scope.offset += 5;
            scope.page += 1;
        });


        elem.find('.page-down').bind('click', function(){
            scope.offset -= 5;
            scope.page -= 1;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

When the page loads it correctly shows page 1 with an offset of 0. If I change the variable to page=2 and offset=5 then the page loads as would be expected, the values are populated correctly, and the offset correctly shows the subscriptions for indexes 6-10. However, when I click the buttons that the click elements are bound to I don't see the page or offset variables update, even though I can verify through the Chrome Dev Tools that the click bindings are being hit. It seems the directive is not passing the scope variables to the parent controller properly?

Comment: have you defined module `Baseware`? and inject it to your main module?

Comment: Ahh sorry thats a typo, yes the application bootstraps and runs as expected

Comment: where is the `getSummary` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 separate issues.

The first issue is that you are calling a click handler outside of Angular, so it doesn't know it needs to run its digest cycle. You can solve this by attaching `ng-click` on your `page-up` and `page-down` elements, or by calling `$apply`:

```
elem.find('.page-up').bind('click', function(){
    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.offset += 5;
        scope.page += 1;
    });
});
```

The second issue is that your directive has `scope: true` which means it is inherting the parent (controller) scope via prototypal inheritance. So when your directive starts to set `page` and `offset` onto the scope, it creates new variables on its own scope, which any outer scope like the controller doesn't see:

```
link: function (scope, elem) {
    // Creating new variables on the child scope

    scope.offset = 0;
    scope.page = 1;

    elem.find('.page-up').bind('click', function(){
        // Updating variables on the child scope

        scope.offset += 5;
        scope.page += 1;
    });
}
```

So if you add `{{ page }}` and `{{ offset }}` markup inside the `app-table` element, you'll see it update. But if you add that markup  outside of the `app-table` element (but still inside your `ng-controller` element) you will see that the controller does not have the new information.

It should work if you set `scope: false`, because then you'd be writing to the same exact scope as the controller.

It can work with `scope: true` if you use objects in your controller instead:

```
scope.pagination = {
    offset: 0;
    page: 1
};
```

Also, I'm not sure if the example presented here is simplified, but you are basically using an Angular directive to do jQuery. Have you considered making an independent `pagination` component, with `scope: "="` (isolate scope)? Then you could explicitly pass in the data it needs (`page`, `offset`, `total`, .etc), and the directive could have its own template.

Answer (score 0):

This is still issue about using `jquery` in `angularjs`.

In fact `offset` and `page` are already changed in your scope, but if you want to reflect them on your view, you have to call `scope.$apply()` to let angular rerender your page.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.summary = {
    subscriptions: {
      labels: [
        {
          name: 'name1',
          subscribers: 'A,B'
        },{
          name: 'name2',
          subscribers: 'A,B,C'
        },{
          name: 'name3',
          subscribers: 'A,B,C,D'
        }
      ],
      total: 10,
      pages: 1
    }
  };
  
  //$scope.offset = 0;
  //$scope.page = 1;
}]);

app.directive('appTable', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      scope.offset = 0;
      scope.page = 1;
      elem.find('.page-up').on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.offset += 5;
          scope.page += 1;
        });
      });


      elem.find('.page-down').on('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.offset -= 5;
          scope.page -= 1;
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
  <div class="app-table col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" app-table>
    <header>
      <span class="col-xs-12">Subscriptions</span>
    </header>
    <div class="pagination">
      <span class="user-controls">
            <span class="page-down glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left">PageDown</span><br>
      <input type="text" ng-model="page" />
      <span>/ {{summary.subscriptions.pages}}</span><br>
      <span class="page-up glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">PageUp</span><br>
      </span>
      <span class="results-text">Results 1 - {{summary.subscriptions.labels.length}} of {{summary.subscriptions.total}}</span>
    </div>
    <table class="col-xs-12 table-striped">
      <thead>
        <td class="col-xs-9">Name</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Subscribers</td>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="label in summary.subscriptions.labels | limitTo: 5 : offset">
          <td class="col-xs-9">{{label.name}}</td>
          <td class="col-xs-3">{{label.subscribers}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    {{offset}}
    {{page}}
  </div>
```